# Python dictionary: how to take the input string and define dynamic dictionaries with dict names as words in the string, while execution

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to create a funtion which takes 3 arguments which are as follows.

```
path = "['pma']['device']['clock']"
key = 'key'
value = 'value'
```

the function should take these values as input and return a dictionary with sub-dictionaries inside and key,value added at the end dict.

```
Expected output = {'pma':{'device':{'clock':{'key':'value'}}}}
```

**The challenge I am facing is, how to take the input string and define dynamic dictionaries with dict names as words in the string, while execution.**

Comment: *dictionary with sub-dictionaries inside and key,value added at the end dict* - pretty unclear, show the expected output according to your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this code

```
path = "['pma']['device']['clock']"
key = 'key'
value = 'value'
pl = path.replace('][', ',').replace(']', '').replace('[','').replace("'","").split(',')
res = {}
for item in reversed(pl):
    if item == pl[-1]:
        res[pl[-1]]={key:value}
    else :
        res = {item: res}
```

Output :

```
{'pma': {'device': {'clock': {'key': 'value'}}}}
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR THE HELP.

Comment: Just one more suggestion, 
What will I do when there is a List in the branch, for example,
path = ['pma']['device']['clock'][0]['address-pool']

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `re.findall()` function and recursive `makeDictFromPath()` function:

```
import re

path = "['pma']['device']['clock']"
key = 'key'
val = 'value'

def makeDictFromPath(result, path):
    result[path[0]] = {}
    if len(path) > 1: return makeDictFromPath(result[path[0]], path[1:])

    return result

result = {}
keys = re.findall(r'\[\'(\w+)\'\]', path)

makeDictFromPath(result, keys).get('clock', {})[key] = val
print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'pma': {'device': {'clock': {'key': 'value'}}}}
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR THE HELP. 
Just one more suggestion, 
What will I do when there is a List in the branch, for example,
path = ['pma']['device']['clock'][0]['address-pool']

Comment: @UnnikrishnanV, you should specify how should look the expected output for your new input